# What has changed in PHP 8 which causes imap_msgno() to claim "Bad message number" when it worked perfectly yesterday with PHP 7.4.12?

Tags: php, imap, php-8

I have some nightmarish IMAP code which took me an eternity to code. I made it when 7.x was current PHP, and I've been using it to fetch my e-mails into my PHP system for years, without any problems like this.

Yesterday, PHP 8 was finally released as "GA" (stable). I updated. And sure enough, there always has to be some weird issue when updating software. Now, my IMAP code is flooding the logs with this nonsense:

```
imap_msgno(): Bad message number
```

Relevant code snippet:

```
$message_number_array = imap_search($specific_mailbox_connection, 'ALL', SE_UID);

if (count($message_number_array))
{
    foreach ($message_number_array as $message_number)
    {
        $header_info = imap_headerinfo($specific_mailbox_connection, imap_msgno($specific_mailbox_connection, $message_number));
```

I have double-verified that `$message_number_array` is indeed an array of integers and nothing else. And it comes straight from `imap_search`. How can these numbers *possibly* be "bad message numbers"?

Yes, I consistently use UIDs everywhere. Nothing about my code was changed from when it was working perfectly well with PHP 7.4.12 yesterday.

As usual, there's zero relevant information online when I search.

What should I do in this situation and this *kind* of situation? I don't even understand how this is *possible* -- let alone how I would fix it.

Comment: Hey, I did most of the recent changes on the IMAP extension to try to bring it up to norm with the rest of the PHP extensions in PHP 8.0, however I'm far from an IMAP expert and might have made an error.

I'm assuming it didn't but just to double check, no warnings/notices were emitted right?

Comment: @Girgias Well, I've downgraded back to 7.4.12 (and now 7.4.13), so I can't check again, but the only thing logged was the `imap_msgno(): Bad message number` stuff. Not sure if it was called a "notice" or "error", but it was certainly logged in the PHP error log.

Comment: I am talking under your current PHP version (so 7.4.13). If not then it's a bug that I introduced, if so can you please open a ticket on https://bugs.php.net/ so that I can reference this and get the fix for 8.0.1.

Having a reproducible would be excellent. :)

Comment: @Girgias There's nothing logged/wrong whatsoever in 7.4.x, correct. Only PHP 8. I actually went to the bugs site and looked at the form, but I can't make a reproducible example because my IMAP code is *massive*, and one would have to actually connect to an IMAP server for this to happen.

Comment: We got some utilities for us to set up an IMAP server/mailbox, but just open a ticket and I'll try to figure out a reproducible just include the relevant code snippet as you did here.

Comment: @Girgias https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80438

Comment: This issue still exists in 7.3, 8.0 and 8.1 as of December 5th, 2021.

Comment: A comment on https://www.php.net/imap_mail_move suggests that messages aren't actually moved and instead a copy is made and then the original deleted. If that is true (I still need to verify) then you have to determine the new id and fluff "id" every single time!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if can help but according to source code changes in php_imap.c they have promoted some warnings to errors two months ago, it could be possible that your code was working with warnings and you haven't notice it ?

You can check the changes in this blame view :

[change to promote warnings to errors](https://github.com/php/php-src/blame/77582ec13f5cc9fa214e729e355e80af4403e152/ext/imap/php_imap.c)

Star in line 144, and as you can see in imap_msgno source (line 2835) is calling PHP_IMAP_CHECK_MSGNO.

Without see any code nor logs is difficult to say what is happening apart from that code change.

Comment: I sadly was unable to extract anything useful from that page and was forced to downgrade to 7.4.12. Will wait for 8.1 or something, I guess. Feels terrible. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in PHP8, see

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80438

Comment: Well, it's "known" now, because the person who posted this question also filed the bug. And by the time you wrote this comment, a fix had already been identified and prepared for inclusion in the next release, so it was already known to be a bug only in 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else searching in future, this was [confirmed as a bug in the implementation](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80438) and [immediately fixed](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6468).

The fix [was included in PHP 8.0.1](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.0.1), released on 7th Jan 2021.

For anyone who wants to help make sure these kinds of bugs get caught before "general availability", please help by testing your code against Beta and Release Candidate builds. There's always a lot of functionality not covered by automated tests which will only be spotted once someone tries to run their real code.

Comment: I was running 8.0.3 and `imap_msgno` was returning `0`. Came across this thread and updated to the latest `8.0.6` and it's *still bugged* / returning `0`. I then downloaded PHP 8.1.0 and it's *still* broken. In edition one can no longer sign in to report or comment on bugs at php.net!